# How can I stop the scrolling animation on a listview?

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to stop a `ListView` from scrolling? I currently have a `ListView` with a margin on top to show an image view that will sit behind there. My goal is to cover the `ImageView` that will sit behind the `ListView` when the person is scrolling up, as the `ListView` is scrolls up it will also close the margin it has eventually hiding the `ImageView` that sits behind it. I currently have it doing just that but I'm trying to figure out how to stop the scrolling animation on the `ListView` till the `ListView` closes it's margin. ('mainItemDisplayer' is the `ListView`.)

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            //mainItemDisplayer.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, 0, 0, 0));
            int scrolledOffset = mainItemDisplayer.getVerticalScrollOffset();

            if (scrolledOffset!=mainItemDisplayer.mInitialScroll) {
                //if scroll position changed
                boolean scrollUp = (scrolledOffset - mainItemDisplayer.mInitialScroll) < 0;
                mainItemDisplayer.mInitialScroll = scrolledOffset;

               if (scrollUp){
                   Log.d("Scrolling", "UP");

               } else {
                   //mainItemDisplayer.setEnabled(false);
                   //Scrolling down
                   Log.d("Scrolling", "DOWN");
                   FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mainItemDisplayer.getLayoutParams();
                   //layoutParams.setMargins(0, mainItemDisplayer.mInitialScroll, 0, 0);

                   layoutParams.height += scrolledOffset;
                   mainItemDisplayer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                   //((FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mainItemDisplayer.getLayoutParams()).setMarginEnd(mainItemDisplayer.mInitialScroll);
                   //mainItemDisplayer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                   return;
               }
            }
            //mainItemDisplayer.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve, but it sounds like what you need are only two xml attributes for your listview :

```
paddingTop="<yourmargin>dp"
```

and (the trick!)

```
clipToPadding="false"
```

.